# Screenshot not share in facebook titanium

Tags: facebook, titanium, screenshot

```
 var media;
    Titanium.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e) {
     media=e.media;       
           }
        );


        var data = {
        link: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript",
        name: "Best online Javascript reference",
        message: " Javascript reference",
        caption: "Timbodi",
        picture: media,
        description: "This section of the site is dedicated to JavaScript-the-language, the parts that are not specific to web pages or other host environments...",
        test: [ {foo:'Encoding test', bar:'Durp durp'}, 'test' ]
    };
    facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed', data, 'POST', showRequestResult);
```

share the screen shot image, but the image show in facebook is different.
please help i am new in titanium.

Comment: What kind of image you are seeing on facebook

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100007942808110

Comment: @Wahhab_mirza see facebook id : facebook.com/profile.php?id=100007942808110

Comment: no, i am not got the answer.